# Profiling DB2 connection with MiniProfier

Tags: ado.net, db2, miniprofiler

I'm trying to add MiniProfiler to my DB2 connections.  Below is my simplified code.

```
public void InitializeConnection()
{
    DB2Connection cnn = new DB2Connection("connection String");
    var profiler = 
         new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, MiniProfiler.Current);
    IDbCommand c = new DB2Command();
    c.Connection = profiler ;
}
```

My problem is occurring in the last line where the profiler is assigned to the DB2Command's Connection property. I'm getting the below error.

Unable to cast object of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection' to type 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection'
I've tried a couple of different casting ideas and nothing has worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going at it backwards. You're assigning the connection to the `ProfiledDbConnection` class (as seems to be correct, [based on the docs](http://miniprofiler.com/#DbConnection) on the MiniProfiler website).

However, you're then creating a DB2-specific command object, and trying to assign the [`ProfiledDbConnection`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Data/ProfiledDbConnection.cs) class to the connection object.

I think what you want to do is call `profiler.CreateDbCommand()`, which will create a [`ProfiledDbCommand`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Data/ProfiledDbCommand.cs) object that uses the DB2Command class "under the covers".

Answer (score 0):

The `DB2Command.Connection` property is of the type `DB2Connection` (as the error message helpfully tells you). Try `DbConnection` instead:

```
c.DbConnection = profiler
```

[More in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2CommandClassDbConnectionProperty.html)

Comment: That would be ideal except DbConnection is a protected property, not a public for the DB2 DB2Command.  Also, the class is sealed, so it cannot be inherited.

Comment: The manual says otherwise: `public DbConnection DbConnection {get; set;}`. And why do you need to inherit from `DB2Command`?